# PYTHON installed on PC, (have PYTHON ICON) no LINUX: how do I compile my 1st program?

Tags: python, terminal, compilation

Just getting started using PYTHON.
I am not working AT THE COMMAND LINE  (not on UNIX,  not on LINUX).
I have a DESKTOP folder with   prog1.py
and from the PC --> START  -->  I get to the  PYTHON  ICON.
How do I use this "PC environment / non-unix command line" to compile and run ?
Thank you - - -  Cesar

Here is what is installed.
 PYTHON 3.8 (64-bit)
 -AND-  IDLE PYTHON 3.8
 -AND-  MANUALS

I typed my first program `prog1.py` and it is on the PC DESKTOP

Which ICON do I choose to compile and run prog1.py

```
# Program to add two numbers,  `prog1.py`    
num1 = 15
num2 = 12


# Adding two nos
sum = num1 + num2 

# Printing values
print("Sum of {0} and {1} is {2}" .format(num1, num2, sum))
```

Comment: Python does not need to be “compiled” like with C++ for example.

Answer (score 1):

If python is in your PATH, you can go on your terminal, cd into your prog1.py folder and type:

```
python prog1.py
```

If python is not on your PATH, you will have to type the full path to python:

```
{path_to_python} prog1.py
```